# Running first Instance of while

Tags: c++, while-loop, ternary-operator

The assignment:

> Write a program that loops indefinitely. In each iteration of the loop, read in an integer `N` (declared as an int) that is entered by a user, display N/5 if N is non-negative and divisible by 5, or -1 otherwise. Use the ternary operator (?:) to accomplish this. (Hint: the modulus operator may be useful.)

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
     int x;
     cin>>x;
     while(1) {
         cin>>x;
         int result;
         cout<<"             "<<endl;
         result = (x>0 & (x%5==0)) ? int(x/5) : -1;
         cout<<result;
     }
}
```

I am able to do the question 
but the first run of the program does not gives output

Comment: This Is not homework !! I am trying to do http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/assignments/

Comment: Still this would be termed as Homework :-)

Comment: Why do you need this  cin>>x; before while(1) ?

Comment: @RahulRa: The idea of the homework tag is that people give answers that help learning instead of answers that fix the problem. I could have told you to delete `cin>>x`, but that wouldn't have helped you.

Comment: Oh I got my carelessnes , Moderators please delete this question

Comment: Assignments == Homework. But you can delete questions yourself if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Go through the program line by line. With `cin>>x`, you read a number into x. Line 6 is a `while (1)`, 1 is true, so you go into the loop. The next `cin>>x` reads a number into x, overwriting the previous contents.

Answer (score 1):

```
(x>0 && (x%5==0)) ? int(x/5) : -1; 
     ^^
```

I think you intend to use Logical `&&` operator and not the bitwise `&` operator.

Additionally, You are reading into `x` twice and overwriting the first read value.

Comment: Ya but In TERNARY operators we can just use & and it will work !!{for evaluation}

Answer (score 0):

Okay. First thing first. You should know C++ logical AND operator is "&&" and not "&" (the one you used). Have a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/.

Answer (score 0):

Hint 1: Do you really need the singleton `cin` just above the while Loop?

Hint 2: Do you want to print the blank line with newline above the result?

Hint 3: Do you need to print the result without a newline?

Hint 4: Did you intend to use a bitwise `&` instead of logical `&&`.?

Optional

Hint 1: Do you need to case the division by `5` to `int`?